# Remove a post when the user gets removed from the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an api with node, where I have a post model which references a user.

What I want to occur is when I delete a user, any post which is associated with that user to also get removed from my mongodb database.

How can I implement this functionality?

Comment: Use [**findOneAndDelete**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete) for user deletion, that in turn would return you the deleted user `doc`. Use that to delete user's posts.

Comment: @ambianBeing Thank you. That solution also works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the `_id` of the user before deleting and then use that user id to delete related posts